# Is it possible to generalize Mapper and Reducer classes?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

For example:
If I have a class that

```
extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
@Override
reduce(Text,Text,Context){
  sameFunction();
}
```

AND another reduce method that support

```
@Override
reduce(LongWritable,Text,Context){
 sameFunction();
}
```

Both reduce functions do the same thing but lets just assume the output format it different, could this be generalized than repeating the same reduce method?

It would be even better if We could have a general Reducer that will support different Input format and output format.

Could this be achieved or we would have to stick to duplicate reducer and reduce?

Comment: what does sameFunction() do?

Comment: Okay maybe above  example isn't good but let assume that I want the job to support  output both comma separated Text and Avro. So the functionality of the reducer will be same but only the output differs.
If iextends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>  then as expected that reduce will expect context.write(Text,Text) therefore, I'll not be able to use output context.write(AvroSchema().exampledata,NullWritable.get()) without creating a new class and extending Reducer<Text,Text,AvroSchema,NullWritable>. Is there anyway that I could reuse the code?